# How to keep backslash when reading from a file?

Tags: bash

When I use "cat test.file", it will show

```
printf "This is a test log %d \n, testid";
 1
  2
```

When I use the bash file,

```
IFS=""
while read data
do
    echo "$data"
done << test.file
```

It will show

```
printf "This is a test log %d n, testid";
 1
  2
```

The "\" is gone.

Is there any way that I can keep the "\" and space at the same time?

Comment: I think you mean `< test.file`, not `<< test.file`

Comment: `info bash`, search for the "read" commmand: "The backslash character '\' may be used to remove any special meaning for the next character read and for line continuation."  (This doesn't solve the problem, but it explains it.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try using `read -r`.

From the man page:

> -r
>       If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape
>   character.
>       The backslash is considered to be part of the line. In particular,
>   a backslash-newline
>       pair may not be used as a line continuation.

Execute this to test it:

```
read -r a < <(echo "test \n test"); echo $a
```

Answer (score 0):

Preserve whitespace and backslashes: `IFS=`, `read -r` and `printf '%s\n' "input"`

Test input: `test.xml`:

```xml
<test>
  <path>\\this\is\a\path.txt</path>
</test>
```

```bash
cat test.xml | while IFS= read -r f; do
  printf '%s\n' "$f" 
done
```

Outputs:

```xml
<test>
  <path>\\this\is\a\path.txt</path>
</test>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data="$(cat < test.file)"
for line in $data
do
echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: Simpler: `data="$(cat test.file)"` or `data="$(<test.file)"`

Comment: You don't need to slurp the entire file into `$data`.  `for line in $(<test.file) ; do echo "$line" ; done`

Comment: You're still going to need to play with the IFS to prevent bash from interpreting them as separators.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Store the original IFS
OIFS="$IFS"
# Update the IFS to only include newline
IFS=$'\n'
# Do what you gotta do...
for line in $(<test.file) ; do 
    echo "$line"
done
# Reset IFS
IFS="$OIFS"
```

Pretty much where you were headed with the IFS plus Keith Thompson's suggestion.

Comment: This does not address the original question imho, it does not leave `\` in the content.